# sendGrid mail does not works with import

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

The above uses require to import sendgrid. The above code works.

But as I am using ES6 syntax, I can't use require and have to use import instead.

```
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

So, I wrote this code, but it gives error as variable is undefined (reading setApiKey). And when I remove that line. It gives error as variable is undefined (reading send).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to import the `MailService` property:

```
import { MailService } from "@sendgrid/mail";

const sendgridClient = new MailService();

sendgridClient.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY || "");
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I could not get `import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';` to work, as recommended across other SO answers.

Comment: Was having the same problem getting sendgrid to work in a node module-based project. This solution worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is a closing bracket at the end of the import statement. I think you missed to remove it when you converted. Please remove it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There is default mail service, so below is enough, we don't have to create new instance.

```js
import mailService from "@sendgrid/mail";

mailService.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY ?? "");
```